# Handle the dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi all How to handle the  dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event in javascript of asp.net.
I'm able to handle it in codebehind but every time page_loag event is firing.

Comment: If you want to get up and running on client side javascript try [Knockoutjs JS library][1] and Jquery. Both are boon to server side programmers. 

Knockoutjs provides binding feature for select & input fields. There is a learning curve ofcourse


  [1]: http://www.knockoutjs.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle this in JavaScript..

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlID" onchange="JavaScript:JSFuntionName();">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the autopostback property from the dropdownliat and use the onchange attribute to fire a javascript function.